# Update code from GitHub in Xcode4

Tags: xcode, git, github

The question is very simple: how do I can update my project from GitHub repository directly in Xcode (ver. 4.2.1)?
I've set up my repo and commands commit/push work fine, but I can't update my project code.
Do you have suggestions? Otherwise, can I do this using git commands from terminal?

Thanks, Vi.

Answer (score 1):

there is a step-by-step explanation for that right here: http://www.mindthe.net/devices/2011/04/28/12-steps-to-using-github-with-xcode-4/

enjoy :)
sebastian

Comment: then maybe this documentation will help you : http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/SCM/SCM.html

Comment: Nothing to do... I can commit and push code but update commands from repository do not want to work!

Comment: have you tried out the github client for mac: http://mac.github.com/
probably the best option here.